# Apply wildcard to a key of assoc. array

Tags: php, arrays, wildcard

I have read similar questions on this site, but still could not figure out how to apply it to my array. I have the following:

```
$var = array(
  [docs] = > array (
     [0] => array(
       [title_en] => some_title_en,
       [text_en] => some_text_en
      )
     [1] => array(
       [title_es] => some_title_es,
       [text_es] => some_text_es
      )
     [2] => array(
       [title_de] => some_title_de,
       [text_de] => some_text_de
      ) 
   )
 )

foreach ($var['docs'] as $array) {
   echo 'Title: '.$array['title_?'];
   echo 'Text: '.$array['text_?'];
}
```

Is there a way to output this array with wildcard for the keys: `title` and `text`, something like: `$array['title_*']` and `$array['text_*']` ?

Comment: Consider restructuring your array: `$var = array('docs' => array (
'en' => array(
'title' => 'some_title_en',
'text' => 'some_text_en'
),
'es' => array(
'title' => 'some_title_es',
'text' => 'some_text_es'
),
'de' => array(
'title' => 'some_title_de',
'text' => 'some_text_de'
) 
)
);`

Comment: I can't because that's an array result I get from an external source, I'm only outputting the results

Comment: What prevents you from taking that array you get and construct a new one that looks like what Mark Baker proposed?

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't retrieve the original array from the external source, and restructure it within your own code before outputting the results

Comment: That sounds good. I'll work on it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Amal Murali, h2ooooooo: I have upvoted both answers as both are viable options. I'll try to apply them and then will see which one I'll eventually go with, and then I'll come back to accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider restructuring your array as mentioned by Mark Baker. It doesn't matter if you get the data from an external data source:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'docs' => array(
        array(
            'title_en' => 'some_title_en',
            'text_en' => 'some_text_en',
        ),
        array(
            'title_es' => 'some_title_es',
            'text_es' => 'some_text_es',
        ),
        array(
            'title_de' => 'some_title_de',
            'text_de' => 'some_text_de',
        ),
    )
);

$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $category => $texts) {
    $newArray[$category] = array();

    foreach ($texts as $textsLanguage) {
        foreach ($textsLanguage as $key => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^(.*)_([a-z]{2})$/', $key, $match)) {
                if (!isset($newArray[$category][$match[2]])) {
                    $newArray[$category][$match[2]] = array();
                }

                $newArray[$category][$match[2]][$match[1]] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [docs] => Array
        (
            [en] => Array
                (
                    [title] => some_title_en
                    [text] => some_text_en
                )

            [es] => Array
                (
                    [title] => some_title_es
                    [text] => some_text_es
                )

            [de] => Array
                (
                    [title] => some_title_de
                    [text] => some_text_de
                )

        )

)
```

Now you can simply use

```
$lang = 'en';
var_dump( $newArray['docs'][$lang]['title'] ); //string(13) "some_title_en"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/143683)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up using my own workaround:

```
foreach ($var['docs'] as $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if (substr($key,0,5) == 'title' || substr($key,0,4) == 'text') {
          $lang = explode('_', $key);
          $sufx = $lang[1];
       }
   }
   echo 'Title: '.$array['title_'.$sufx];
   echo 'Text: '.$array['text_'.$sufx];
}
```